# Can I render to several displays from the same JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, x11

I have 4 Java applications rendering some AWT graphics. They all render to different X displays, which we configure at JVM startup time.

I would like to have them run from the same JVM. This way, I launch one Java app, and it will open up four screens, which render their stuff to different displays.

Is that possible in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810539/save-jframe-location-in-multi-display-environment). Could help you too.

Basically you need to instantiate your JFrame's with the graphics environment of each device from `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()`